# How to politely ask if a specific person (by name) is available in a professional setting/store

Tags: words

I couldn’t find the right search terms to trigger an existing answer. I often go to a store where I have somewhat of a regular relationship with one of staff members. Sometimes they’re in the back, and I would like to ask if they are available by name, but in a polite manner.

How would I ask “Excuse me, is Tanaka available/here?”

Comment: Welcome to JL SE! Might you be able to provide evidence of your own research/thoughts about how you would go about saying that, so this is not a translation question (and therefore off-topic – see https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @henreetee I think this question is general enough not to count as a translation request. At the least, I would say, it is useful beyond this one person and therefore has it's place here. That is assuming it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Garbaz I appreciate that what is strictly a translation question or not is up for debate, and can appreciate that the question could be generally useful :) but, even so, I think some original attempt by the OP would for me move it squarely on-topic. Of course, apart from it being the nice/respectful thing for question askers to demonstrate their own research, it also helps others to answer the question in a more helpful way (e.g. if there are fundamental misunderstandings of grammar, those can be cleared up; if there are more subtle nuances at play, then those can be discussed).